# Making trademarks in an open source project on Github with Apache 2.0 License

Tags: licensing, license-notice, trademark

I have published a [FOSS project](https://github.com/brianrisk/SYNTHBLAST) on Github and am interested in retaining the trademarks to the project name and graphic elements.

From the Apache 2.0 license:

> 6. Trademarks. This License does not grant permission to use the trade names, trademarks, service marks, or product names of the Licensor,
>    except as required for reasonable and customary use in describing the
>    origin of the Work and reproducing the content of the NOTICE file.

Is there a standard way to declare trademarks, copyrights etc. in code repositories?  For example, do project owners typically have a "COPYRIGHT.md" file?  Or is there typically a "Trademarks" section of the "README.md"?  (I've never seen this before.)  Are there any templates/good examples/best practices for how to do this?

Comment: Which elements of your project do you believe meet the threshold to count as a trademark?

Comment: @PhilipKendall In this case the name and logo

Comment: You could look into how this is done by Mozilla for the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

There is no consistent practice around this.  A few projects put a TRADEMARK.md file in their main repositories. More put a few lines in their README files.  The most common practice, though, is to put the trademark information on your project website.